# Плюгавый, ползать

Tags: этимология, славянизмы

Можно ли отнести слова пл**ю**гавый и ползать к этимологически однокоренным, исходя из:

1. Исторического писания глагола ползать как "пл**е**жить";
2. Чередования согласных г->ж;
3. Чередования согласных ю -> е (кл**ю**в -> кл**е**вать, бл**ю**й -> бл**е**вать)